# Apparent PHP Syntax Error

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error, qr-code

Basically, I've been trying to make a simple Wordpress widget that displays a QR code with the URL of the current page. I'm using a modififed version of the simple text widget that parses PHP too.

```
function the_qrcode($permalink = '', $title = '') {
    if($permalink && $title == '') {
        $permalink = 'http://eternityofgamers.com/forums';
        $title = 'Forums';
    }

    echo '<img src="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' .$permalink. '" alt="QR: ' .$title. '"/>;
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this? I get a 500 error when I add it to `functions.php`.

Comment: Wait, do you get a 500 error when you try to use it or when you add it and run the server?

Comment: Unfortunately, a `500 internal server error` doesn't tell us much. It is a very general HTTP status code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at StackOverflow's syntax highlighting. You're missing a closing single quote `'` on your string at the end of the function's last line:

```
echo '<img ...' .$title. '"/>;
                             ^
```

Comment: Glad someone saw that I needed help with the Syntax highlighting and not the error. Thanks. I can't believe I missed that though. >_<

Answer (score 1):

Close the last single quote on the echo line to be:

```
echo '<img src="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' .$permalink. '" alt="QR: ' .$title. '"/>';
```